# Nesting ISERROR with multiple functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I inherited a project that uses the formula below and I am having a hard time following it. The original author of this formula is no longer with the company and nobody else can follow it to use it for other applications. How does the nested MATCH function work with a IF and ISBLANK. Does anybody follow this? Just FYI the range *Summary Data Entry Sheet'!$A$3:$A3* refers to the cell just above this formula (formula is located here: *Summary Data Entry Sheet'!A4*)

{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107),1,COUNTIF('Summary Data Entry Sheet'!$A$3:$A3,'Item List'!$C$3:$C$107)),0))),"",INDEX('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107),1,COUNTIF('Summary Data Entry Sheet'!$A$3:$A3,'Item List'!$C$3:$C$107)),0)))}

Answer (score 2):

The MATCH returns the relative row number of the first cell in 'Item List'!$C$3:$C$107 that is not blank (`ISBLANK('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107)`) and not already in the list being created in `Summary Data Entry Sheet` column A (`COUNTIF('Summary Data Entry Sheet'!$A$3:$A3,'Item List'!$C$3:$C$107)`).

This formula must be placed in Row 4 of Column A.  The  `$A$3:$A3` reference will change as it is copied/dragged down to always include A3 to the cell directly above as the range in which to count.

That relative row number is used in the INDEX() to return the value from Item List'!$C$3:$C$107.

Eventually the match will run out of items in the list that satisfy the conditions and will return an error.  The outer IF test for this to return a null string when it errors.

With later versions of excel it can be simplified with IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK('Item List'!$C$3:$C$107),1,COUNTIF('Summary Data Entry Sheet'!$A$3:$A3,'Item List'!$C$3:$C$107)),0)),"")
```

The `{}` around the formula are put there by excel to denote an array formula.

This accomplish by using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to confirm the formula upon exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put the `{}` around the formula.  Do not type them directly.